# input row number and column number and output a string of rows and columns

Tags: python

I have a task I can't solve:
take as input two numbers and a symbol. Output a grid made up entirely of the chosen symbo, with the number of rows matching the first number input and the number of columns matching the second number input:
For example, the three input values 3,7 and &, result in the output:

&&&&&&& 
&&&&&&& 
&&&&&&&

```
NumberOfColumns = int(input("Enter number of columns"))
Symbol = input("Enter the chosen symbol")
RowCounter = 1
ColumnCounter = 1
for RowCounter  in NumberOfRows:
    for ColumnCounter  in numberOfColumns:
        print(symbol)
print(symbol)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a little bit of editing was needed in code

```
NumberOfRows = int(input("Enter number of columns"))
NumberOfColumns = int(input("Enter number of columns"))
Symbol = input("Enter the chosen symbol")
RowCounter = 1
ColumnCounter = 1
for RowCounter  in range(NumberOfRows):
   for ColumnCounter  in range(NumberOfColumns):
       print(Symbol,end="")
   print()
```

Here, since NumberOfRows and NumberOfColumns are integers, so when using for loop you should enclose then in `range()` as `int is not iterable`. Moreover by default print(), will end with a new line, which could be changed using `print(value,end="")`. This ensures print end with a blank space.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need to print the grid to the terminal, the following should work:

```
rows = int(input('Enter the number of rows: '))
columns = int(input('Enter the number of columns: '))
symbol = input('Enter the symbol: ')

# I use an `_` since the variable isn't being used
for _ in range(rows):
    print(symbol * columns)
```

Comment: it still doesn't work this is what i get: `Enter the number of rows: 3
Enter the number of columns: 2
Enter the symbol: &
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loop6.py", line 3, in <module>
    symbol = int(input('Enter the symbol: '))
  File "<string>", line 1
    &
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
`

Comment: Oeps! I left an extra `int` conversion in there for your symbol, and your symbol isn't able top be converted to an `int`, hence the crash. I edited the code, so it should be working for you now!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it really simply with list comprehensions, ie:

```
cols = int(input("Enter number of columns:\n > "))
rows = int(input("Enter number of rows:\n > "))
symb = input("Enter symbol:\n > ")

text = '\n'.join([symb * cols for _ in range(rows)])

print(text)
```

Output:

```
Enter number of columns:
 > 5
Enter number of rows:
 > 3
Enter symbol:
 > &
&&&&&
&&&&&
&&&&&
```

**EDIT:**

Errors in your current code:

```
NumberOfColumns = int(input("Enter number of columns"))
Symbol = input("Enter the chosen symbol")
RowCounter = 1
ColumnCounter = 1
for RowCounter  in NumberOfRows:
    for ColumnCounter  in numberOfColumns:
        print(symbol)
print(symbol)
```

- The main reason your current code wouldn't have run is that integers can't be used in a for loop. Instead of doing `for RowCounter  in NumberOfRows:`, you could have done `for RowCounter  in range(NumberOfRows):`.
- Another error would come from the line `for ColumnCounter  in numberOfColumns:`, even if you changed it to `for ColumnCounter  in range(numberOfColumns):`. The issue here is that you store the number of columns in the variable `NumberOfColumns`, not `numberOfColumns`, so you would have got a `NameError` if your code got that far.
- A bug comes from the line `print(symbol)`. By default, `print` ends your text with a newline character (`\n`), so your output would not have formed a series of rows, instead a single column. You can do it with `print`, by using `print(symbol, end='')`, which tells `print` that you don't want a newline after your text.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement prints a newline after every character, you're presumably getting just one & symbol per line. The way you stop it doing this depends on whether you're using python 2 or python 3.

Python 2:

```
# Add a comma at the end
print symbol,
```

Python 3:

```
# Use the "end" keyword argument
print(symbol, end="")
```

I think you're probably using python 3, given that you're using the print function.

You will then need an extra print call after each row to give you the newline you are now missing:

```
for RowCounter in range(NumberOfRows):
    for ColumnCounter  in range(numberOfColumns):
        print(symbol, end="")
    print()
```

You're also printing symbol again at the end. I don't know why you're doing this, you'll probably need to remove that line.

Comment: This code still won't run because your trying to iterate over an int...

Comment: True. I've edited the reply to add ranges. Of course, it still won't run because the OP hasn't defined the number of rows, but I was just copy/pasting his original code to demonstrate where the print went, not to fix the rest of his code

Answer (score -1):

```
[["&"] * 7] * 3
```

Here is a fun solution